# Count variable is not incrementing properly

Tags: c++, arrays, traversal

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string arr[8];
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        if(arr[i]== "JAVA"){
            count+=1;
        }


    }
    
        
    
    cout<<"JAVA lecture is repeating"<<" "<<count<<" "<<"times";
}
```

It is printing: "JAVA lecture is repeating 2 times" instead of "JAVA lecture is repeating 4 times", for sample input of: "JAVA JAVA DataStructures DBMS JAVA JAVA Python DataStructures"

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ekx3.png)

Comment: Works for me, on gcc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first line `Total 8 lectures on Monday` is included in the input you receive. You only read 8 words: {`Total`, `8`, `lectures`, `on`, `Monday`, `JAVA`, `JAVA`, `DataStructures`} => Only two `JAVA` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code, it DOES output the result 4 as we expected.

[the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfQHc.jpg)

Comment: I edited my question and put an image link in it.

Comment: Please use answer sections for answers only, and not for updates for the original question. If you have figured out the solution yourself and want to answer your own question, please do so by giving an explanation of what you have done. Also, please do not post images of text, simply copy-paste and format accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna do something like this instead.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str,word;
    getline(cin,str);
    getline(cin,word);

    stringstream ss(str);
    int cnt=0;
    while(ss>>str){
        if(str==word)
          cnt++;
    }
    cout<<cnt<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would anyone who wants to write **good** code ever have `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in their code? You're lucky I'm (nearly) out of downvotes.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry sir, I will change it ASAP.